# Keyboard backlight not working for some keys

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, backlight

Many similar questions I've read here have to do with backlights not working at all or when dimmed.

My problem is that the number 6 key is not illuminating. All other keys are working as they should.

Any ideas how to diagnose and fix this?

[image: Single key not illuminating]

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem to me. I suggest taking it to an Apple Store or a reputable Apple repair shop if the laptop is under warrantee.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 SMC is responsible for Backlighting

Comment: Let me add that when this happened to two of my clients, SMC resets did nothing to fix the problem. YMMV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, unless a SMC reset doesn't work (Shut down -> Press Shift-Control-Option and Power Button at the same time for 10sec -> release keys -> Press power button), it is a hardware problem. If it's under warranty, Apple should fix it, if not, a 3rd party repair shop should be able to fix it for a reasonable price.

Comment: Thanks. The SMC reset did nothing for this particular issue but has helped in the past. I have 3 years of Applecare+ so I'm going to take it in to them.